# Laravel 5.2 : How to get belongsTo through model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `vehicles` model with `car_id`, `year`, `license_plate` field.

I have `Car` model with `car_class_id`, `car_brand_id`, `name` field.
Car name contain something like (Civic, Pajero, etc)

I have `Car_brands` with `name` field. (Honda, Toyota)

I have `Car_classes` with `name` field. (SUV, MPV, Truck,etc)

`car_id` in `vehicles` model belongs to `Car` model.

`car_class_id` belongs to `car_classes` and `car_brand_id` belongs to `car_brands`

How I can get vehicles list where have car_class name MPV?

Is my relationship good design or I just put car brand name and car class name on vehicles table?

Answer (score 2):

You can try it as:

```
Vehicle::whereHas('car' , function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('car_classes' ,fucntion($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'MPV');
    });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution must be like this

```
Vehicle::whereHas('car' , function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('car_classes' ,function($query2) {
        $query2->where('name', 'MPV');
    });
})->get();
```